# Static HTML end-user CMS?

Tags: html, css, static, content-management-system, netlify-cms

Probably a very stupid question but I've been out of the game a long time now! For years I have been developing websites using HTML and CSS and making very responsive and modern websites that also work very well with mobile and then uploading them to a webserver. I have recently been using Netlify as my server of choice.

The catch is that Netlify is a static webserver and I am trying to have some sort of CMS for my clients to edit their websites without looking at code. The problem is that I want to use the same CSS and HTML code for my client's existing websites without having to completely rebuild them in JS/React.

I tried using Netlify CMS + Gatsby template with the hope that I could just paste my HTML and CSS code into it but I was mistaken!

Is there any method for me to use my existing HTML and CSS static websites on an end-user CMS?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try a CMS that is generating static pages.
I am working with one (imperia CMS) and there the html of the template/result page is enhanced with markers/placeholders for editor generated content. Basically you start with the original page, mark what you want changeable and have the end result generated. There are more bells and whistles available. It is for profit though, so you might want to explore what your options are.

Hope that helps.